# How can I union two lists in the given way?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
list1 = {{-21, -1}, {-19, -9}, {-19, 7}};
list2 = {{-4, -1}};
```

I would like to have this list

```
list = {{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19,7}}}
```

I tried

```
Union[list1, list2]
```

and got,

```
{{-21, -1}, {-19, -9}, {-19, 7}, {-4, -1}}
```

How can I get it to show this?

```
 list = {{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19,7}}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Tuples[{list2, list1}]
(* {{{-4,-1},{-21,-1}},{{-4,-1},{-19,-9}},{{-4,-1},{-19,7}}} *)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Outer[List, list2, list1, 1]
(* {{{-4,-1},{-21,-1}},{{-4,-1},{-19,-9}},{{-4,-1},{-19,7}}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
list1 = {{-21, -1}, {-19, -9}, {-19, 7}};
list2 = {{-4, -1}};

Catenate[{list2, {#}}] & /@ list1

Join[list2, {#}] & /@ list1
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, 7}}}

Answer (score 8):

anther option

Given

```
lis1 = {{-21, -1}, {-19, -9}, {-19, 7}};
lis2 = {{-4, -1}};
```

Then

```
Map[{First@lis2, #} &, lis1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And for fun:

```
Join[Riffle[lis1, lis2], lis2]
RotateLeft[#, 1] & /@ Partition[%, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

```
l1 = {{-21, -1}, {-19, -9}, {-19, 7}};

l2 = {{-4, -1}};

l3 = {{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, 7}}};
```

Using `Thread`:

```
Activate[Reverse /@ Thread[{l1, Inactive[l2[[1]]]}]] === l3

(*True*)
```

Or using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[l1, {a_, b_} :> l2~Append~{a, b}, {1}] === l3

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Two additional methods:

```
Distribute[{list2, list1}, List] == list
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Thread[{list2[[1]], list1}, List, {2}] == list
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {{-21, -1}, {-19, -9}, {-19, 7}};

b = {{-4, -1}};

SequenceCases[Riffle[a, b, {2, -1, 2}], {a_, b_} :> {b, a}]
```

{{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, 7}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Distribute[{list2, list1}, List]

(* {{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, 7}}} *)
```

or

```
MapApply[{list2[[1]], {##}} &, list1]

(* {{{-4, -1}, {-21, -1}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, -9}}, {{-4, -1}, {-19, 7}}} *)
```